# Where can I find the MySQL log file in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

I use PHP to access MySQL in XAMPP. My question is where I can find the MySQL log file if there is a DB error.

Also, can I change the default location/name of that log file?

Thank you

///// Based on the coments //////

```
mysql> show variables like '%log_file%';
+---------------------------+------------------------------------+
| Variable_name             | Value                              |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------+
| general_log_file          | C:/xampp/mysql/data/mysql.log      |
| innodb_log_file_size      | 5242880                            |
| innodb_log_files_in_group | 2                                  |
| slow_query_log_file       | C:/xampp/mysql/data/mysql-slow.log |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you do

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%log_file%';
```

it will show exactly where they're being written.

Comment: Interesting, but what if you have an error that prevents mysql from starting, so you can't ask mysql where the log is?

Comment: then look in the my.ini/my.cnf file for the setting

Comment: how do you get it to return the full path to where the log is though? This only shows relative path.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is a bit old, for [MySQL 5.1+](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html)

you may use the queries:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
SET GLOBAL general_log_file = 'my_log.log';
```

First will enable loging (which may be off by default)
and the second select updates the preferred file (by default under C:/xampp/mysql/data/).

**NOTE:** On windows 8 you may have to run your SQL IDE as ADMINISTRATOR for this commands to get saved.

**NOTE2:** you can also set this in the config, go to `path_to_xampp/mysql/` and edit **my.ini**
(copy from **my-default.ini** if it does not exists) and add the settings there:

```
[mysqld]

general_log = 'ON';
general_log_file = 'my_log.log';

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a *.err file.

You will find it here : C:\xampp\mysql\data

To trace you error correctly, open it with Notepad++ for example and Start Mysql. You Should see the error at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try looking at localhost/phpmyadmin/ and click on the Variables tab.

Answer (score 1):

On mac, it's likely to be at:

/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql

If there are a lot of error files there, do ls -la to see which one is most recent and most likely.